# String Containing Exact Substring from Substring List

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, match, contains

Scala beginner here, I'm trying to find all the **tweets text that contain at least one keyword in the list of keywords** given.

Where a tweet:

```
case class Tweet(user: String, text: String, retweets: Int)
```

With an example `Tweet("user1", "apple apple", 3)`

Given that **wordInTweet** should return true if at least one keyword in the list keywords can be found in the tweet's text.

I tried implementing it like the following:

```
def wordInTweet(tweet: Tweet, keywords: List[String]): Boolean = {
    keywords.exists(tweet.text.equals(_))
}
```

But, it also returns **true** if a tweet's text is **music** and a given keyword's text is **musica**.

> I'm struggling to find a way to return true ONLY if the tweets
>   contains the exact same keyword's text.

**How can I achieve this?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the below answered worked for you, but consider [List#sliding](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@sliding(size:Int,step:Int):Iterator[Repr]): `scala> "my tweet".sliding("my".size).toList
res2: List[String] = List(my, "y ", " t", tw, we, ee, et)
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it would help if you consider the `keywords` as a Set, given that sets have a very efficient `belongs` function.

```
keywords: Set[String]
```

Then we need to test every word in the tweet, as opposed to the complete text. This means that we need to split the text into words. We find an example of that everywhere with the ubiquitous "wordCount" example.

```
val wordsInTweet = tweet.text.split("\\W")
```

Next, we put things together:

```
def wordInTweet(tweet: Tweet, keywords: Set[String]): Boolean = {
   val wordsInTweet = tweet.text.split("\\W")
   wordsInTweet.exists(word => keywords.contains(word))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @maasg. Unluckily, I cannot change the method signature, it was given to me like that, so, I can't change it to a `Set[String]`. And, leaving it a `List[String]` I get: `Type mismatch, expected: (String) => Boolean, actual (String) => String`.

Comment: Then use the `contains` function of `List`.