# Text containing exact string from list of strings

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pattern-matching, contains

I'm trying to find all the texts that contain at least one keyword in the list of keywords given.
This is similar to this answer: [String Containing Exact Substring from Substring List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41282670/string-containing-exact-substring-from-substring-list)

However, I need to expand it so that it can work with multiple words, for example matching 'united states' and not simply 'usa'.

```scala
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1, "usa of america"),
  (2, "usa"),
  (4, "united states of america"),
  (5, "states"),
  (6, "united states")
)).toDF("id", "country")
df.registerTempTable("df")

val valid_names = Set("usa", "united states")

def udf_check_country(valid_words: Set[String]) = {  udf {(words: String) => words.split(" ").exists(valid_words.contains) } }

var df2 = df.withColumn("udf_check_country", udf_check_country(valid_names)($"country"))
df2.registerTempTable("df2")

df2.show()
```

Where I get the new column failing for the last case of 'united states'.

```scala
+---+--------------------+-----------------+
| id|             country|udf_check_country|
+---+--------------------+-----------------+
|  1|      usa of america|             true|
|  2|                 usa|             true|
|  4|united states of ...|            false|
|  5|              states|            false|
|  6|       united states|            false|
+---+--------------------+-----------------+
```

How can I make it work for keywords with multiple words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your rules, you can simply add another another condition iterating your `valid_names` against the whole string, like:

```
valid_words.exists(words.contains) || words.split(" ").exists(valid_words.contains)
```

That will make that `id` 4 and 6 also return `true`.